# unistd : no such file or directory

Tags: c++, unistd.h

I have the following `test.cpp` file :

```
#include <unistd>

int   main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I just want to compile this but I still have the following :

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp:1:18: fatal error: unistd: No such file or directory
 #include <unistd>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

I found `unistd.h` at `/usr/include/unistd.h`. and my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable was empty so I set it at `/usr/include` (with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include`) but the problem remains.
What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the header is `unistd.h`, not `unistd`. And LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used to locate shared libraries, not header files.

Comment: My bad, you're right.